# Exactly how does a nonce and client nonce prevent a replay?

Tags: security

I understand how a nonce and client nonce prevent password attacks via rainbow tables etc...but im not exactly clear on how they help prevent replay attacks. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 11):

Probably you know the definition of Replay Attack, so going straight to example on how Replay Attack carried-out and how to prevent it using nonce.

**How is a Replay Attack carried-out?**

1. User Alice wants to buy something from [www.iBuy.com](http://www.iBuy.com), but [www.iBuy.com](http://www.iBuy.com) wants Alice to prove her identity.
2. In order to prove her identity, Alice sends her `Hashed [Credentials]` to [www.iBuy.com](http://www.iBuy.com), it validates and accepts Alice to their website.
3. Alice orders her required item and requests to ship to her residential address.
4. Meanwhile, communication session between Alice and [www.iBuy.com](http://www.iBuy.com) has been eavesdropped by malicious user Bob and he retrieved Alice's `Hashed [Credentials]` from the communication channel session.
5. After Alice and [www.iBuy.com](http://www.iBuy.com) communication session ended, Bob connects to [www.iBuy.com](http://www.iBuy.com) and sends Alice's `Hashed [Credentials]` (which is retrieved from step 4) to prove Alice's identity and not Bob's identity to [www.iBuy.com](http://www.iBuy.com), which [www.iBuy.com](http://www.iBuy.com) accepts and thus it allows Bob to enter [www.iBuy.com](http://www.iBuy.com) as Alice.
6. Then, Bob changes Alice's ordered item's shipping address to his address. Now item is going to ship to Bob's residential address, and not to Alice's address.

So,

- Bob possessed Alice's `Hashed [Credentials]` (from step 4), **REPLAYED** the action and submits Alice's `Hashed [Credentials]` to [www.iBuy.com](http://www.iBuy.com), which it thinks Alice is the one who submits the `Hashed [Credentials]`, but really Bob replayed Alice's `Hashed [Credentials]`.

**How to prevent the Replay Attack using nonce?**

If [www.iBuy.com](http://www.iBuy.com) requires Alice to send `Hashed [Credentials + non-repetitive Nonce sent by www.iBuy.com to Alice]`, then even though Bob eavesdropped, retrieved and REPLAYED the hashed value, [www.iBuy.com](http://www.iBuy.com) denies the request, because the nonce sent by [www.iBuy.com](http://www.iBuy.com) to Alice is now different, subsequently the hashed value is also different now and certainly the hashed value is not the one expected by [www.iBuy.com](http://www.iBuy.com).